# MSBuild failing in Cpp.Targets searching for 'True.dpr', with a new XE4 project

Tags: msbuild, c++builder, delphi-xe4, c++builder-xe4

I am encountering some odd `msbuild` errors with a project in RAD Studio XE4, and am seeking help to diagnose what's going on. I've been encountering this for a couple of weeks now but have not succeeded in solving it myself - time to ask more widely. Symptoms are:

- With a project that has been built and run from within the IDE, `msbuild Project.cbproj` appears to work
- Running `msbuild Project.cbproj /t:Clean` works, and deletes intermediate files fine.  A visual scan of the output doesn't show any unusual files being deleted - just .obj files, linker state files, the final EXE, etc.
- But running `msbuild Project.cbproj /t:Build` or just plain `msbuild Project.cbproj` after either cleaning or on a clean checkout **fails** with the following error message:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.5420 [Microsoft .NET
>   Framework, Version 2.0.50727.5472] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation
>   2007. All rights reserved.
>
> Build started 12/09/2013 10:35:03. Project
>   "C:\projects\Project.cbproj" on node 0 (default targets).
>
> _PasDepCheck:   Modified: Source\Common\resample.pas
>   _PasCoreCompile:   Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 25.0   Copyright (c) 1983,2013 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(191
>   1,5): error F1026: File not found: 'True.dpr' Done Building Project
>   "C:\projects\Project.cbproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:\projects\Project.cbproj" (default target) (1) -> (_PasCoreCompile
>   target) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD
>   Studio\11.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(1 911,5): error F1026: File not
>   found: 'True.dpr'
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```

Some things strike me about this:

- It lists two versions of .Net at the top, an older one in square brackets. Could it be loading or using parts of two frameworks?
- `True.dpr` does not exist, nor can I find an entry manually searching the `.cbproj` file for a `True.dpr`, or for a `True` entry that looks (to me) like it could be misinterpreted as a project name. (If you are not familiar with Delphi, a .dpr file is an old-fashioned project file - it contains the entry point. Building one may imply msbuild is finding a source or project entry somewhere. 'True' seems to me like the .cbproj file is being misinterpreted or is corrupted - but it's brand new, so shouldn't be, and it works from within the IDE.)

Other information about the system and projects:

- The project is being upgraded from RAD Studio 2010. However, the project file was created in XE4 *from scratch*, ie it's brand new, by creating a new project in the IDE and adding the existing units (Delphi and C++ files.)
- The project is a C++ project with one or two Delphi units. You can see it is falling over when compiling a Delphi unit at the start of the compilation. For those not familiar with mixing C++ and Delphi, typically in mixed-source projects the IDE or msbuild would compile the Delphi units first (doing so can create / update C++ headers to interface with the Delphi code.)
- The project is one of a group, but should compile stand-alone.
- I have RAD Studio XE4 installed with Update 1.
- `msbuild` is being launched from the RAD Studio XE4 command line, ie one which uses the `rsvars.bat` file to set up the paths etc.
- In the above output, I have changed our real project name to Project because I don't want to identify it. However, the rest of the output is exact.

Any ideas? I've been trying to solve it for ages, and am stumped.

Answer (score 10):

I just had this same error in Delphi XE5.  Running MSBUILD with `/v:diag` outputs the complete commandline for DCC32, which had a rogue `true` amongst the parameters.

The following page pointed to the solution: http://wiert.me/2013/11/20/when-the-delphi-xe5-commandline-compiler-fails-with/

In this case I was passing the parameter `/p:DCC_DebugInformation=true`, but this could also be in the .dproj file.  Changing `true` to `2` fixed the problem - i.e.

```
MSBBUILD /p:DCC_DebugInformation=2 project.dproj
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, in the hope it will be useful to future readers.

This comment was key:

> It lists two versions of .Net at the top, an older one in square
>   brackets. Could it be loading or using parts of two frameworks?

It turned out not to be the project name after all. Instead, we had a custom build logger written to use with the msbuild version shipped with RS2010. It was built with a different version of .Net, and loading the logger DLL seemed to cause major problems inside msbuild - understandable since I guess it meant it was loading two different versions of the .Net runtime.

**Why this answer might be wrong:** I did try command lines without the custom logger (slowly trimming down our old working command lines bit by bit and then working up again to find the problem.)  Those *sans*-logger builds failed too, which leaves me a bit puzzled. It's possible some intermediate output from a crashing instance of msbuild confused subsequent runs, or something in the .Net runtime cached the use of the DLL or the different loaded runtimes. I do know that the custom logger did cause problems for sure, and *deleting* the DLL itself (which was when everything really began working) as well as just removing it from the command line fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A similar answer to that of @michael-g, only using the GUI, can be found at this link: https://blog.spreendigital.de/2014/03/14/w1030_warning_xe5/

(i.e. go to Delphi debugging settings and change "Debugging information" to something else other than the existing "True".